# Redis Testing Client not running in the network and RabbitMQ running but not connected in Docker-Compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis, rabbitmq

My DockerFile is:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY packageDocker.json package.json
RUN npm install --production
RUN apk update && apk add lsof
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Docker-Compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    user: "node:node"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
      - redis-testing
      - rabbitmq-testing
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: client
    ports:
      - "6390:6379"
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbit
    ports:
      - "5674:5762"
      - "15674:15672"
  redis-testing:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6392:6300"
    container_name: client-testing
    volumes:
     - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
     - ./redis-server.log:/var/log/redis/redis-server.log
    command: sh -c "redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf && redis-server --bind redis --port 6300"
  rabbitmq-testing:
    image: rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq-env.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
    ports:
      - "5673:5673"
      - "15673:15673"
```

Redis Client is working properly, Redis Testing Client Container is also running but when lsof -i:6300 is ran in web container, nothing is shown but when lsof -i:6379 is ran, redis running is shown and RabbitMQ container is running but lsof is not showing anything and neither any connection  is able to take place with RabbitMQ! What wrong I am doing?